# Prove $\forall U \subseteq \mathbb R^2\,,\exists \Phi\in \rm{Lin}(\mathbb R^2, \mathbb R^2): null(\Phi) = U$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, invariant-subspace

The title pretty much describes it. To be proven: for every subspace $U \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ there exists a linear map $\Phi$ with $\rm null(\Phi) = U$.

What would be the general approach to the problem? I've already proved it for $U = \{0\}$ and $U = \mathbb R^2$, but I can't think of an example of a map matrix in the case $U = \{tx |~ t \in \mathbb R\}$ (in other words the subspace of all lines through the origin). Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case $U=\{tx: t\in \mathbb R\}$ there exists $y$ such that $\{x,y\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb R^{2}$. Define $\Phi (ax+by)=(0,b)$. Then $\Phi$ is linear and its kernel is $U$.

Comment: So we're basically using the fact, that every vector in $R^2$ can be represented as a linear combination of the base vectors (in this case two non-colinear vectors $x$ and $y$, for the first of which we know, that it's in our subspace $U$). Then we present the argument of $\Phi$ in that form and set the output to always be $b$? But wouldn't that mean that the output is a real number (a scalar) and not a vector? Hence, the map would not be linear?

Comment: I have edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you a lot!